# php displays one div before other divs

Tags: php, html, css

```
public function body() {
    global $control;

    return '
    <div id="bodyTop"></div>
    <div id="bodyContainer">'.$control->pages().'</div>
    ';

    }//body
```

This is the function that I am using to display the content for all pages and the $control->pages() function does the following

```
public function pages(){
    $pages = $_GET['pages'];

    switch ($pages) {
        case 'startseite':
        echo $this->startseite();
        break;

        case 'rezepte':
        print 'rezepte';
        break;

        default:
        echo 'startseite';
        break;
    }

}
```

and then:

```
public function startseite () {

    $text = '<div style="float:left">Hello world</div>';

    return $text;
}
```

but when it displays the content it does it wrong and I dont understnad what is the problem!

here is how it displays:

```
<div style="float:left">Hello world</div>

<div id="bodyTop"></div>
<div id="bodyContainer">
</div>
```

and here is how it should display it:

```
<div id="bodyTop"></div>
<div id="bodyContainer"><div style="float:left">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
echo $this->startseite();
```

you're echoing, so it gets printed before `body()` gets returned.

Based on your snippet, you probably want:

```
return $this->startseite();
```

in your `$control->pages()`

Answer (score 0):

`pages()` echos, rather than returning a string.